# Sharing data between directives

Tags: angularjs

I have some data called `foo` which lives in a scope which is parent to three children:

```
<div ng-init="foo=[1, 2, 3]">
    <bar foo="{{foo}}" baz="{{odp}}" />
    <mpq foo="{{foo}}" bats="{{maktz}}" />
    <ktr foo="{{foo}}" otr="{{ompg}}" />
</div>

bar.scope = {foo: '=', baz: '@'};
mpq.scope = {foo: '=', bats: '@'};
ktr.scope = {foo: '=', otr: '@'};
```

What is the best way to share `foo` between those three directives? Options include:

- Use an isolated scope to pass in `foo` three times, thereby duplicating it across four scopes
- Have the child directives inherit the parent scope, and find `baz`, `bats`, or `otr` on `attrs`
- Put `foo` on the `$rootScope` and inject that into the child directives

Or is there another approach that is better?

Comment: Other option might be using a service and injecting it into your directives, but this really depends on the nature of your data.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can create a factory that you can pass to each directive or controller. That will make sure you only have one instance of the array at any given time. EDIT: The only gotcha here is to make sure you're setting reference types and not primitive types on your directive scopes, or you'll end up duplicating the values in each scope.

[Here is an example on Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZOjr2)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  //set up the items.
  angular.copy([ { name: 'test'} , { name: 'foo' } ], dataService.items);
});

app.directive('dir1', function(dataService){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h3>Directive 1</h3>' + 
    '<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">' + 
      '<input type="text" ng-model="item.name"/>' + 
    '</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.data = dataService;
    }
  };
});

app.directive('dir2', function(dataService){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h3>Directive 2</h3>' + 
    '<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">' + 
      '<input type="text" ng-model="item.name"/>' + 
    '</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.data = dataService;
    }
  };
});

app.directive('dir3', function(dataService){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h3>Directive 3</h3>' + 
    '<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">' + 
      '<input type="text" ng-model="item.name"/>' + 
    '</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.data = dataService;
    }
  };
});

app.factory('dataService', [function(){
  return { items: [] };
}]);
```

HTML

```
  <dir1></dir1>
  <dir2></dir2>
  <dir3></dir3>
```

Comment: I considered this, but the angular docs discourage it: http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

Comment: I presume you're talking about this: "Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data." It really depends on what you're doing with the data. If you're manipulating it at all in a uniform way across controllers/directives/etc (which most people would be), then create a service... otherwise, just stick it in $rootScope. As long as whatever you're doing is easy to follow and, most importantly, doesn't break testability, it's kosher.

Comment: ... as @pkowslowski.opensource said above: It really depends on the nature of your data.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot you can hold it in a service #facepalm.

Comment: Is it realy good way to use services to pass variables? Isnt it antipatern? And actualy if you will change service variable thru function, by ng-click for example, you need to use $scope.$apply to make changes life in other controllers. I don't think services were made to pass variables, but I'm not sure?