# Interaction between directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 2 directives, one that displays a list of objects, and other one that adds objects to that list.
The problem that I have is that the list are tied to another elements list this way:

Main code:

```
<!--main code -->
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <element-a></element-a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <element-a></element-a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <element-a></element-a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <element-a></element-a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Element A template

```
<!-- element-a template -->
<ul>
    <li> 
        <my-element-list></my-element-list>
    </li>
    <li>
        <my-element-list></my-element-list>
    </li>
    <li>
        <my-element-list></my-element-list>
    </li>
    <li>
        <my-element-list></my-element-list>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My List Template:

```
<!-- my-element-list template -->
<button type="button" data-ng-click="addElement()">Add</button>
<ul>
    <li>
        my element data
    </li>
    <li>
        my element data
    </li>
    <li>
        my element data
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm new to angular, but I don't want to have the add directive on each list, as that would have a lot of not needed code added to the html.
Also the add is a directive that has a template, etc, that is suppossed to show a modal dialog which will request the element data.

Is this the correct approach for doing this?
How can I get the add modal dialog displayed when the add button is clicked?
I tried with `$broadcast` and `$emit`, but the add directive is not a parent/child of the element list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two possibilities:

- Create an service for the communication
- Use the `$rootScope` and events

Also:

- [Directive-to-directive communication in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628616/directive-to-directive-communication-in-angularjs)
- [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)
- [AngularJS: Communication between directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780402/angularjs-communication-between-directives)

And:

- http://www.thinkster.io/pick/sMgLuIxf02/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication
- http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/12/17/communicating-between-directives-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try and go about this a different way. Your list should be generated from an array of items in your controller, and then rendered into the template using the built-in Angular directive `ng-repeat`. Then, adding new items to the list should be as simple as making sure the `addElement()` function in your controller is adding items to the array. If each element in your list also needs it's own template, look into using the `ng-include` directive within the `ng-repeat` loop.

[ng-repeat docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat)

[ng-include docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude)

Comment: That's not the problem. The items are rendered that way. Just showing the data structure to show why $emit and $broadcast does not work.