# How do send json objects as part of the state transition to another controller in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers FundsController and FundRequestContoller. FundRequestController is used to show fund request received  to an user. And FundsController contains a form which has an option to select on of my friend and amount that a user wish to send to his friend.

And, when ever a user accept a particular fund request by a friend, a state transition should happen to navigate the user from FundRequestController view to FundsController view where the friend id and amount to requested be pre-populated.

I would like to create a json object and share this object with FundsController so that when it is initialized the friend id and amount can be pre-populated using json object.

I dont want to use query params since too much information will be displayed to user in the browser url.

How can I share a json objects from one controller to another controller that can be used to initialize the other controller??

Answer (score 2):

Use factory to create your service which holds the shared data. This service is then injected into both of your controllers as a dependency.

app.factory("sharedDataService", function() {
            return {
                yourData: "whatever"
            };
        });

see this :

- great SO answer and example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13482919/36546
- Video here: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to make factory file as common to both controllers .

[More Info](http://www.i-avington.com/Posts/Post/angularjs-using-a-service-to-communicate-between-two-different-controllers)

http://plnkr.co/edit/UA28cXfF0I8r3M54DyYa?p=preview

Another simple method is that make one function as global and share data

Controller 1

```
$scope.shareData( data ) = function(){

  $scope.sampleFunction( data) ;

  };
```

Controller 2

```
$rootScope.sampleFunction( data ) = function(){

  console.log(data);
  // your logic

  };
```

[More Info](http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/03/communicate-with-controllers-in-angular.html)