# AngularJS share data bettween parent and child scope directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a widget like directive called waComments, it loads components via a RESTful service and displays them. In my view I'm using ng-repeat to loop over them and to render them with a button that if pressed Shows a new reply to form. This his handled by the waCommentsReply directive. One waComments widget has many child directives of type waCommentsReply. When the form is filled and submitted I want to add the new comment on top of my comments list. So both directives have to share the comments data.

I've tried to implement this here [Sharing data between directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482351/sharing-data-between-directives) but without much success, the comment data is not updated when I add a new comment. I see that the RESTful API calls work and the data is returned, so this is not an issue.

Why is my implementation of [Sharing data between directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482351/sharing-data-between-directives) not working in my case?

waCommentsReply directive:

```
waFrontend.directive('waCommentsReply', ['$rootScope', 'Comment', 'WaFormValidation', 'WaCommentStore', function($rootScope, Comment, WaFormValidation, WaCommentStore) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/stubs/comment-form.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            replyTo: '@replyTo',
            replyFormList: '=replyFormList',
            loggedIn: '@loggedIn',
            model: '@model',
            id: '@id',
            cancelButton: '@cancelButton'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.comments = WaCommentStore;
            if ($scope.cancelButton == undefined) {
                $scope.cancelButton = true;
            } else {
                $scope.cancelButton = false;
            }

            $scope.comment = $scope.commentForm = {
                Comment: {
                    author_name: '',
                    body: '',
                    model: $scope.model,
                    foreign_key: $scope.id,
                    parent_id: $scope.replyTo
                }
            };

            $scope.$watch('replyFormList', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    $scope.replyFormList = newValue;
                }
            });

            if ($scope.loggedIn == undefined) {
                $scope.loggedIn = false;
            }

            /**
             * Handles the submission and response of a reply
             *
             * @return void
             */
            $scope.reply = function() {
                Comment.add($scope.comment).then(function(result) {
                    if (result.status == 'fail' || result.validation != undefined) {
                        $scope.validationErrors = result.validation;
                        WaFormValidation.validate(result.validation, $scope.commentForm);
                    } else if (result.status == 'success') {
                        //$scope.$parent.comments.unshift(result.data.comment);
                        //$scope.comments.unshift(result.data.comment);
                        $scope.comments.comments.unshift(result.data.comment);
                        //WaCommentStore.append($scope.model, $scope.id, result.data.comment);
                        $scope.comments, $scope.id, result.data.comment
                        $scope.comment = {};
                        $scope.replyFormList[$scope.replyTo] = false;
                    }
                });
            };

            $scope.close = function() {
                $scope.comment = {};
                if ($scope.replyFormList[$scope.replyTo] != undefined) {
                    $scope.replyFormList[$scope.replyTo] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

WaCommentStore directive:

```
waFrontend.factory('WaCommentStore', function() {
    return {
        comments: []
    };
});
```

waComments directive:

```
waFrontend.directive('waComments', ['$rootScope', 'Comment', 'WaCommentStore', function($rootScope, Comment, WaCommentStore) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/stubs/comments.html',
        scope: {
            model: '@commentModel',
            id: '@commentFk'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.comments = WaCommentStore;
            $scope.loaded = false;
            $scope.loadedMore = true;
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.loggedIn = false;
            $scope.paging = {};
            $scope.replyFormList = {};

            Comment.comments($scope.model, $scope.id).then(function(result) {
                $scope.comments.comments.push.apply($scope.comments.comments, result.data.comments);
                $scope.loggedIn = result.data.loggedIn;
                $scope.paging = result.paging.Comment;
                $scope.loaded = true;
            });

            $scope.loadMore = function() {
                $scope.loadedMore = false;
                if ($scope.paging.nextPage == false) {
                    //return false;
                }
                var options = {
                    page: $scope.paging.page + 1
                };
                Comment.comments($scope.model, $scope.id, options).then(function(result) {

                    $scope.comments.comments.push.apply($scope.comments.comments, result.data.comments);
                                        $scope.paging = result.paging.Comment;
                    $scope.loadedMore = true;
                });
            };

            $scope.submitComment = function() {
                //alert($scope.author_name + $scope.body);
            };

            $scope.reply = function(replyId) {
                $scope.replyFormList[replyId] = true;
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

since in both directive you defined scope: {} basically it means you defined those directives to use isolated scope.
with isolated scope, a scope/directive can't see what is in the parent scope.
however parent scope, can be affected by the child scope changes with 2 way binding definition.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: "a scope/directive can't see what is in the parent scope" <- that is not true. $scope.$parent. But doing this is an anti-pattern in angular. Also to bind the data I would have to pass it to my child directives.

Comment: its 100% true. first make sure you understand what isolated scope actually means, than we can talk about hacking angular and working the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the shared data like this

```
waFrontend.factory('WaCommentStore', function() {
   var comments = [];

   var getComments = function() { return comments; }

   var setComments = function(data) { comments = data; }

   return {
        getComments : getComments ,
        setComments : setComments 
    };
});
```

I wanted to put it as a comments, but it would have been difficult to understand for you.

Please let me know if this works, else I will delete this answer.

Comment: did the answer helped